# in C programming, is there anyway to get return value of function in child struct(struct in struct)?

Tags: c, object, struct

I'm trying to return some function in the double struct.

It is always ok when you get return value in single struct structure.
What I'm trying to do is define struct in struct structure. That is, making child struct in parent struct. For example, as seen on the source below, I've made two struct 'Person' and 'Machine', and then I would like to add Person struct under the 'Machine' so that I get double struct structure, which can be used to define machineperson. then would like to get some return value of function in one of struct in parent struct which is machine->person->name..
Everytime I get return in buff->PD, there some error occurs. Of course it's ok I use single struct like Person or Machine, which is not what I intend to do.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS     
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct _Person {    
    char name[20];            
    int age;                  
} Person;             

typedef struct _Machine {   
    char address[100];        
    Person PD ;
} Machine;               

Person *GetPersonData(){
    Person *pd = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person)) ;
    strcpy(pd->name, "GETperson");
    return pd ;
    //free (pd) ;
}
Machine *GetMachineData(){
    Machine *md = (Machine*)malloc(sizeof(Machine)) ;
    strcpy(md->address, "GETmachine");
    return md ;
    //free (md) ;
}
Person *GetPDdata(){
    Person *pd = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person)) ;
    strcpy(pd->name, "GOT Machine people");
    return pd ;
    //free (md) ;
}

int main(){
    Person *p1;     
    Machine *m1 ;   
    Machine *buff ; 
    p1 = GetPersonData() ;
    m1 = GetMachineData() ;

    buff->PD = GetPDdata() ; // Error code
    m1->PD.name = buff->PD.name  ;  // Error code      

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: the standard says that identifiers starting with underscore (`_`) followed by a capital letter (`A` to `Z`) are always reserved for any use.

Comment: `GetPDdata()` returns `Person *` but you `buff->PD` type is `Person`. Check the compiler error message.

Comment: You are assigning pointers to non pointer instances. Are you well versed in pointer vs non pointer variables? If not read up on that.

Comment: At this point: `buff->PD = GetPDdata()` buff is not initialized yet, so it points anywhere. Even if you get rid of the type mismatch, the program will behave undefinedly (probably crash) at this point.

Comment: so if i would revise, GetPDdata() should return Machine.Person? but it does not work this way. MayurK

Comment: Erich Kitzmueller situation is same here when I add buff = GetMachineData() ; to initialize buff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the structure definition. Since you want to allocate the person inside the machine directly, I would suggest a different definition for the structure `Machine`

```
typedef struct _Machine {   
    char address[100];        
    Person *PD ;
} Machine;
```

Then you only need one function to get the person data. You can remove the function `GetPDdata`

The function `GetMachineData` can be modified to get both machine and person data as follows

```
Machine *GetMachineData(){
    Machine *md = (Machine*)malloc(sizeof(Machine)) ;
    strcpy(md->address, "GETmachine");
    md->PD = GetPersonData();
    return md ;
}
```

The above is the recommended method, but you can also get the machine and person data separately in main.

```
// keeping GetMachineData unchanged from original question.
int main(){   
    Machine *buff ; 
    buff = GetMachineData();
    buff->PD = GetPersonData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  buff->PD = GetPDdata() ; // Error code
```

Here buff is not initialized with any value. you need to allocate buff first

```
m1->PD.name = buff->PD.name  ;  // Error code
```

Here you can not assign strings directly , you need to use strcpy for that

Comment: thankyou ChauhanTs, understood second problem.
As for the first one situation is same here even though I added buff = GetMachineData() ; to initialize buff.

Comment: typedef struct _Machine {   
    char address[100];        
    Person PD ;
} Machine; here you need to take pointer  Person *PD, or if you still do not want pointer than you can not directly assign buff->PD = GetPDdata() , but you need to copy the content using memcpy

Answer (score 0):

```
 buff->PD = GetPDdata() ; // Error code
```

This won't work because GetPDdata() returns a 'pointer' to a Person, not a person itself.
So you need to either do:

```
 buff->PD = *GetPDdata() ; // Error code
```

to copy from the pointer returned by `GetPDdata()` (in which case the memory allocation you did becomes kind of pointless).

Or else you could use:

```
p1 = GetPDdata();
```

which is fine because p1 is also a pointer to a person.

```
m1->PD.name = buff->PD.name  ;  // Error code
```

The problem here is that you cannot assign one array to another. You have to copy character by character or use something like `memcpy`.